# How to install latest WireShark?

Tags: wireshark

I see that the latest Wireshark has been release. I would like to have it since it has some features that I need.

https://packages.qa.debian.org/w/wireshark.html

Unfortunately, if I use `sudo apt-get install wireshark` the newest version I got only 3.0.5.

How can I install the lastest one ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Wireshark](https://askubuntu.com/questions/700712/how-to-install-wireshark). Wireshark PPA generally offers latest version as soon as packed as deb file. As of now, the PPA has 3.0.7 while the latest release is 3.2.0. You can either wait for them to build or build from source.

Comment: ah yes, I know there is always a way to build from the source (cmake, make, ninja...), what I meant is I saw in the link "accepted package", is there anyway I can install it with something like `apt-get`.

Comment: Are you using Debian? If not, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: no. You cannot at the current moment use `apt` or `apt-get` to install the latest version that is bundled. According to the [website](https://packages.qa.debian.org/w/wireshark.html), version 3.2.0 is not yet packaged:

[image]

Even if it was, it is also extremely unstable:

[image]

If you wait for a few days (maybe weeks depending on the motivation of the devs), version 3.2.0 will most likely be packaged, and you will be able to update to the latest version with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Assuming you already have 3.0.5 installed.